# how to validate array response includes values from another array in Karate

Tags: karate

I have an array

```
[{"Id": "123"},{"Id": "1239"},{"Id": "1233"},{"Id": "1235"}]
```

I would like to verify the another array

```
[{"Id": "123"},{"Id": "1239"},{"Id": "1233"},{"Id": "1235"},{"Id": "1236"},{"Id": "1237"},{"Id": "1238"},{"Id": "1239"}]
```

Wrote this code:

```
* def a= [{"Id": "123"},{"Id": "1239"},{"Id": "1233"},{"Id": "1235"}]
* def b= [{"Id": "123"},{"Id": "1239"},{"Id": "1233"},{"Id": "1235"},{"Id": "1236"},{"Id": "1237"},{"Id": "1238"},{"Id": "1239"}]
* match b[*].Id contains a[*].Id
```

I get the below error

```
javascript evaluation failed: b[*].Id, <eval>:1:12 Expected an operand but found *
a[*].Id
  ^ in <eval> at line number 1 at column number 12*
```

Any solutions, please?

Comment: JSON is a string. You have arrays

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JsonPath is supported only on the Left Hand Side of a `match`. Read the docs: https://github.com/intuit/karate#jsonpath-short-cuts

Add one step please:

```
* def expected = $a[*].Id
* match b[*].Id contains expected
```